# Node.js installed via NVM on Linux throwing Permission denied

Tags: node.js, nvm

I've installed node.js using NVM and it has created the relevant folders, suggests that it is running fine on v0.10.38, but when I type in `node` to run, I get `bash: /home/example.com/.nvm/v0.10.38/bin/node: Permission denied`

Any ideas what is stopping it?

Comment: Maybe it needs the executable bit. What's the output of `ls -l /home/example.com/.nvm/v0.10.38/bin/node`?

Comment: Hi fiskeben, thanks for the response. It's `-rwxr-xr-x 1 example.com example.com 11445463 Mar 23 19:52 /home/example.com/.nvm/v0.10.38/bin/node`

Comment: If it's any help, also, I am using one.com web hosting. Could this be restriction set by them? Their customer support is limited. I've opened up the directory in Dreamweaver now, and all permissions seem to be set to 755, except the root, which I have changed - But still no joy.

Comment: Some more hopefully helpful info. This shows node is installed. Just can't get my head around what's stopping it execute :(

`nvm run 0.10 --version
Running node v0.10.38
bash: /home/example.com/.nvm/v0.10.38/bin/node: Permission denied`

Comment: Typing `nvm use 0.12` returns `Now using node v0.12.2` but `nvm current` returns `none`

can anyone explain that to me? Is that normal?

Comment: Hey @SometimesSean I have no clue why the permissions is a problem, but the reason that `nvm current` returns `none` is because you probably haven't set `nvm use 0.10.38` yet. Give that a try and see if it helps your other problem.